# MSIL instructions that load constants

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, cil, il

I just read [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32308/Using-Reflection-Emit-to-Precompile-Expressions-to) and saw and only one  MSIL instruction that loads constants. That's  `ldc.r8`  and that's loads `double` constant.

Now I'm curious about that. I did a google search but barely found something. Can you tell me, what kind of constant load instructions are there in .NET? Where do I read about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One source for the instruction set is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions; you'll see 16 `ldc` instructions there.

If you'd like a more comprehensive source of information, try the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: Is `ldstr` also a loading **constant** instuction?

Comment: @AlanDert by the C# definition of constant, yes.  I don't remember if the CLI spec considers a "literal string" to be a "constant."

Comment: it's odd, there is no instruction `ldc.i4.9`.

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't find `ldc.i4.9`. Why doesn't it exist?

Comment: @AlanDert It doesn't exist because you can't have a separate special short-form load instruction for every integer value, so you have to pick a small number of integer values for which to create a special short-form load instruction.  The small number chosen by the IL designers was 9, covering values 0 through 8.  The decision not to include 9 was an example of "drawing the line..." (between values with special case instructions and those without) "...somewhere."

Comment: @AlanDert if you're looking for 9 because it's the only decimal digit that isn't covered by a special case short-form load instruction, then you're looking for a red herring.  These instructions have nothing to do with decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

Load value of type `float64` onto the evaluation stack as type F (float).

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_r8.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ("Can you tell me, what kind of constant load instructions are there in .NET? Where do I read about them?")

Comment: i added complement about ldc.r8